# Searching Table for Value (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

How can I search a Table row for a certain value?

```
$qry = $connection->prepare("SELECT (row) FROM UserData WHERE * = ''");
```

I tried this but it didn't work.
After I do this can I find which col it was?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to search a row from left to right and check if the value is empty and know which column it was.

Comment: `SELECT (row) FROM table WHERE tablecolumn = ''`

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the question given when there isn't even a clear explanation of what this question is?

Comment: You cannot use a wildcard in the column name: you need to tell MySQL which columns to look into.

Comment: What if I have a lot of column and I want to check all of them from left to right. tablecol1,talblecol2, etc.

Comment: do I have to do one by one? also how can I check if it is true and which col it was.